# 'http://localhost:8080/js/app.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Iam learning spring now. I am using spring boot and thymeleaf template. I did the spring security example provided in spring docs. now i wanted to include js file to implement the remember me functionality in my application so i added **app.js** file in **src/main/resources/js** folder.and my login.html is in src/main/resources/templates folder. and i included

```
 type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"
```

in my html file. i also tried placing the js in same folder,  and in **src/main/resources/static/js**, and included

```
 type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"
```

in my html. But for all cases the browser was throwing **"Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/app.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."** error. I googled for the same i did not get any correct answer. iam newbie to spring and thymeleaf.  kindly help me. thank you. also when i enter login details and press login the browser is displaying my app.js content

**IT GOT SOLVED the error was appearing because of spring security issue. since I was not logged in, spring security was not allowing me to access js file. so i added that URL in spring security permitAll(). it got solved**

Comment: I think its coming in Chrome browser, isn't it?

Comment: Your server is sending the JS file with text/html header instead of text/javascript. You can verify that in the network tab of your browser. Make the necessary changes to the server code.

Comment: @azim: same error is appearing in chrome as well as firefox.

Comment: What does the Spring resource resolver configuration look like? It sounds like the mime type is improperly returned at the container level.

Comment: thank you all for helping me. it got solved.  i added that js URL in spring security permitAll(). it got solved